# Layout to fill all the browser window apart from the navigation bar in Extjs

Tags: html, css, templates, extjs

I'm using Extjs and trying to create a layout that fill all the browser's window apart from the navigation bar.

I created a mapPanel with extjs / geoext which it renders to a div in my content:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        layout: "fit",
        renderTo: "view",
        width:1100,
        height: 500,
        items: {
            layout: "border",
            deferredRender: false,
            items: [mapPanel, tree,
            ]
        }
    });
```

which works fine but the layout is rendered inside the "view" div.
  Can I simply override all the content of the document apart from the navigation bar ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `renderTo: Ext.getBody()` or wrap everything in the [`Viewport`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.container.Viewport.html).

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport',{
    items:[{
        layout: "border",
        deferredRender: false,
        items: [mapPanel, tree]
    }]
});
```

However, neither solution will overwrite everything that is in the body already - you will have to destroy existing content manually.

For instance if you have a splash screen:

```
<div id="splash" style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">
    <br><br>
    <img src="Loading.png">
    <br><br>
    <progress max=100></progress>
    <br><br>
    Loading...
</div>
```

you may want to destroy that screen in your launch method of `Application.js`:

```
launch: function() {
    var splash = Ext.get('splash');
    if(splash) splash.destroy();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I know that  Ext.container.Viewport would be the best solution if I hadn't the navigation bar. Now if I wrap everything in the viewport it fills all the browser's window and its top is hidden by the navbar. I think that the best solution is to destroy that screen in my launch but I haven't found the right way to go yet.